# Custom PrintService in Android not showing up in the list of printers

Tags: java, android, printing

I am attempting to create a custom PrintService plugin for Android, and I have everything except for that it is not showing up in the list of printers under 'All Printers', and says 'Cannot add printers' under my print service if I click "Add printer" manually. I downloaded [this print service](https://github.com/serrexlabs/thermal-printer-service) which does show up in the list of printers, but I can't figure out what is different in their code versus mine.

My PrintService class:

```
public class MyPrintService extends PrintService {

PrinterInfo mThermalPrinter;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mThermalPrinter = new PrinterInfo.Builder(generatePrinterId("USB"),
            "USB Printer", PrinterInfo.STATUS_IDLE).build();
}

@Override
protected void onPrintJobQueued(PrintJob printJob) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyPrintService.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("data", printJob.getDocument().getData());
    printJob.start();
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Nullable
@Override
protected PrinterDiscoverySession onCreatePrinterDiscoverySession() {
    return new ThermalPrinterDiscoverySession(mThermalPrinter);
}

@Override
protected void onRequestCancelPrintJob(PrintJob printJob) {
    printJob.cancel();
}
}

class ThermalPrinterDiscoverySession extends PrinterDiscoverySession {

private PrinterInfo printerInfo;


ThermalPrinterDiscoverySession(PrinterInfo printerInfo) {
    PrinterCapabilitiesInfo capabilities =
            new PrinterCapabilitiesInfo.Builder(printerInfo.getId())
                    .addMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A5, true)
                    .addResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("1234","Default",200,200), true)
                    .setColorModes(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_MONOCHROME, PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_MONOCHROME)
                    .build();
    this.printerInfo = new PrinterInfo.Builder(printerInfo)
            .setCapabilities(capabilities)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onStartPrinterDiscovery(List<PrinterId> priorityList) {
    List<PrinterInfo> printers = new ArrayList<PrinterInfo>();
    printers.add(printerInfo);
    addPrinters(printers);
}

@Override
public void onStopPrinterDiscovery() {

}

@Override
public void onValidatePrinters(List<PrinterId> printerIds) {

}

@Override
public void onStartPrinterStateTracking(PrinterId printerId) {

}

@Override
public void onStopPrinterStateTracking(PrinterId printerId) {

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that it was an issue with the AndroidManifest.xml.

The manifest needs to be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dubtel.print_service">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        r
        <service
            android:name=".MyPrintService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_PRINT_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.printservice.PrintService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.printservice"
                android:resource="@xml/printservice" />
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
 ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```